# Linux exit 0 command without a newline?

Tags: linux, exit, exit-code

Linux how do you use the exit 0 command without a newline?

I want :

```
exit 0
$
```

I have :

```
exit 0

$
```

I have tried:

```
exit -ne 0

echo -ne
exit 0
```

Comment: `exit` has nothing to do with a newline. It just exits the shell. Your issue is elsewhere. See `man 1 bash` "I have tried" `exit -ne 0`, No, no, no. You don't code by just *trying things*, you read the documentation and then form you script (or source code) in compliance with what the documentation says is a valid use of whatever it is you are trying to use.

Comment: Or I guess more appropriate for the `[linux]` tag is the [POSIX exit command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_21) which is identical to that of the bash builtin.